# Stop a tableView cell from being deletable?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Does anyone know how to stop a table view cell from being deletable? I have multiple cells in a table view and I want to only allow the user to delete some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is implement `-tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method in your code & return NO for the rows you want to deactivate deletion possibility.